# How can I tell if a VARCHAR variable contains a substring?

Tags: sql, string, contains, sql-server-2012

I thought it was `CONTAINS`, but that's not working for me.

I'm looking to do this:

```
IF CONTAINS(@stringVar, 'thisstring')
   ...
```

I have to run one `select` or another, depending on whether that variable contains a string and I can't figure out how to get it to work. All the examples I'm seeing are using columns in the contains.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The standard SQL way is to use like:

```
where @stringVar like '%thisstring%'
```

That is in a query statement.  You can also do this in TSQL:

```
if @stringVar like '%thisstring%'
```

Comment: ...that makes me sad. I tried that the other day and it didn't work. I musta typed something wrong because it just worked. I'm chalking that up to doing something late on a Friday before a 3-day weekend. I may have typed the entire statement backwards for all I know. Thanks!

Comment: @Yatrix . . . you can also use charindex('thisstring', @stringVar), if the like doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Asad . . . Of course this will work.  The wildcard `%` matches zero or more characters.

Answer (score 30):

Instead of `LIKE` (which does work as other commenters have suggested), you can alternatively use `CHARINDEX`:

```
declare @full varchar(100) = 'abcdefg'
declare @find varchar(100) = 'cde'
if (charindex(@find, @full) > 0)
    print 'exists'
```

Comment: That's perfect if what you're looking for is one of the wild cards that the LIKE statement uses

Answer (score 8):

```
    IF CHARINDEX('TextToSearch',@TextWhereISearch, 0) > 0 => TEXT EXISTS

    IF PATINDEX('TextToSearch', @TextWhereISearch) > 0 => TEXT EXISTS

    Additionally we can also use LIKE but I usually don't use LIKE.
```

Comment: Agreed, CHARINDEX works perfectly while the use of LIKE is kind of unpredictable. For an example, for some reason LIKE fails to find '[' in a string while CHARINDEX perfectly finds it with no issues.

Answer (score 7):

`CONTAINS` is for a Full Text Indexed field - if not, then use `LIKE`