# How To Filter Data in Database Based on Day of Week?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I  have a column in my database that holds a string on different week days for my contact.

For Example: Contact 1 works Monday and Wednesday.

So in the `Week_Day` column the string for Contact 1 is "Monday, Wednesday". I am trying to only show the rows who work on the current day of the week, the code is below. I tried using the `IN` clause,  but it's not working because I don't have a set day of the week I want to filter. HELP!

```
string today = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yy");

string day = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString();
string find = "select convert(varchar(8), start, 10) AS start, convert(varchar(8), end_date, 10) AS end_date, ContactName, DepartmentName, Hours, Phone, Week_Day from Schedule join Contacts on Schedule.ContactId = Contacts.ContactId inner join Departments on Contacts.DepartmentId = Departments.DepartmentId where @Current BETWEEN start AND end_date AND Week_Day IN (@Day)";
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(find, con);
comm.Parameters.Add("@Current", SqlDbType.Date).Value = today;
comm.Parameters.Add("@Day", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = day;

con.Open();
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = comm;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
GridView3.DataSource = ds;
GridView3.DataBind();

con.Close();
```

Comment: If you can, you would be **much** better to store this as a bit field, so 5 is Monday and Wednesday (Binary 101), you can they do a bit field check on bit 0 to find all people who work on Mondays i.e. `WHERE (WeekDay And 1) = 1`

Comment: It would actually be much better to use a separate Table that assigns persons to weekdays. This way, the database server can use indexes when performing a query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell if a VARCHAR variable contains a substring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265411/how-can-i-tell-if-a-varchar-variable-contains-a-substring)

Answer (score 2):

Well you can get the current day of week (name) like so:

```
string day = DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd");
```

Then you can use that in your `WHERE` query with a `LIKE`. Change your query to have:

```
WHERE Week_Day LIKE @day
```

And add you param for `@day` to include `%` at start and end:

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@Day", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "%" + day + "%";
```

[More info on LIKE here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

---

NOTE: As some comments have already mentioned it would be better to not store the data this way in a single string column, but I have answered based on your question as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps with DateName() and CharIndex()

```
Where CHARINDEX(DateName(WEEKDAY,GetDate()),Week_Day)>0 and...
```

Comment: @musefan I agree, EVERYTHING changes.  The GetDate() could easily become a user supplied date (always my preference).

Comment: ^ My comment seems to have disappeared, and I didn't delete it.... strange